# willMoveToSuperview is called twice

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm adding a view to my view controller. In this view I have implemented `willMoveToSuperview`. Now I experienced that this function is called twice:

1. When the view is added to the superview (as intended)
2. When the current view controller is dismissed (e.g. a new view controller is pushed on the stack of the navigation controller)

Is this the intended behavior? What other method could I use to detect if the current view is added to a superview only? `didMoveToSuperview` seems to do the same. Or should I use a variable which remembers how often the function is called?

**Edit:**

Now I think I found the reason why it is called twice. I'm using a **hide** method to dismiss the view. It's in `C#` but it shouldn't matter here:

```
UIView.Animate (
    0.5, // duration
    () => { Alpha = 0; },
    () => { RemoveFromSuperview(); }
);
```

If I comment this out it isn't called twice. How can I keep the animation and assure that it is only called once?

Comment: What is the parameter passed in each case?

Comment: @Wain: I updated my question. Which parameter do you mean? I use `View.Add` and a *hide* method as seen above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a view is added to a superview, the system sends `willMoveToSuperview:` to the view.  The parameter is the new superview.

When a view is removed from a superview, the system sends `willMoveToSuperview:` to the view.  The parameter is nil.

You can't prevent the system from sending `willMoveToSuperview:` when you remove the view from its superview, but you can check the parameter:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    if (newSuperview != nil) {
        // not a removeFromSuperview situation
    }
}
```